# Как очистить значения в react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется вот такой код:

```
<Select
 options={dangerGroup}
 onChange={(name) => setDangerGroup(name)}
 required
 placeholder ={'Группа опасности'}
/>
```

Селект завернут в форму и нужно при оправке очищать данный селект. Ни как не могу понять как должно работать.

Comment: А вы не вызываете у формы метод `reset`?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду <input type='reset' className='submit'></input> вот это?

Comment: Именно у формы есть метод `.reset()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для очистки выбранного необходимо в свойство value передать пустую строку

```
export default function App() {
  const [dgroup, setDangerGroup] = useState();
  const clear = () => {
    setDangerGroup(""); // Очищаем выбранное
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Select
        options={dangerGroup}
        onChange={(name) => setDangerGroup(name)}
        required
        placeholder={"Группа опасности"}
        value={dgroup}
      />
      <button onClick={clear}>Очистить</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Работающий пример в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-bush-4f8jr5?file=/src/App.js)